# Python 2.7.2 Win32 # Loop Through List, Buffer Part Of List, Call Function Multiple Times, SAME Return

Tags: python, function, loops, return

I have coded up some small Python script that calls a function multiple times. The function should always return other values, because the buffer is always unique (due to `.pop(0)`). But the return is always the same. If I call the function two times like `result1 = x(buffer1)` and `result2 = x(buffer2)` outside of the loop, the results are unique. But as soon as I try to call the function like in the Pseudo- Code, the result is always the same. It seems as if Python is executing the function only once, and then printing the result of it. I have implemented this code in `PHP` and `VB.net`, and it works as it should. It seems to be a specific Python thing. Can somebody please explain. :/

Pseudo- Code

```
function x()
    list = []
    buffer = []
    for l in list:
        buffer.append(l)
        if len(buffer) == y:
            return = x(buffer)
        buffer.pop(0)
```

Python- Code

```
    ema_length = {66:0,74:0,89:0}
    def ema(length):    
        relevant = len(length)
        multiplier = 2 / (relevant + 1)
        sum_vector = 0
        for vector in length:
            sum_vector += vector    
            current_vector = vector
        sma = sum_vector / relevant
        if ema_length [relevant] == 0:
            ema_length [relevant] = sma 
        else:
            ema_length [relevant] = (current_vector - ema_length [relevant]) * multiplier + ema_length [relevant]
        return ema_length [relevant]

    buffer = []
    for d in data:
        buffer.append(d)
        if len(buffer) == 89:
            ema66 = ema(buffer [89 - 66:89]) # should be unique
            ema74 = ema(buffer [89 - 74:89]) # should be unique
            ema89 = ema(buffer [89 - 89:89]) # should be unique
            ema_overall = ema66 - ema74 - ema89 
            buffer.pop(0)
```

Comment: Rather than Pseudo code, it would be more informational to post your actual code..

Comment: You are creating a new `buffer` on every call to your function.. Your previous change would not be visible..

Comment: @RohitJain My bad, sorry

Comment: What is your expected output and what are you getting?

Comment: From that code, it doesn't seem that you will get same value for all three of them..

Comment: What does your data contain (that you are using in for loop??

Comment: Simple floating numbers from a .csv- file. All are unique (converted via float() before appending), but huge file. The output of data is ok. And if I call ema(buffer[x]) OUTSIDE the loop, the values are unique. So it must have something to do with the loop. The values are not unique but different, the output is the same. Instead of 1.0872,89.0293,22.02938 ... always 1.0872, 1.0872 etc.

Comment: As I said.. I'm getting unique result for the same code.. Although I tried it with `data=range(89)`..

Comment: I have tried Python 2.7.2 and 2.7.3 and 3.3.0 on Win7, WinXP and Fedora17: Always the same result. It also does not matter which data I use and it can come from a file or hardcoded - nothing helps. First I thought that my Windows has something, but even on Fedora it shows the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
multiplier = 2 / (relevant + 1) # floats are rounded! => * with 0 => same result
multiplier = float(2) / float(relevant + 1) # unique values! :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your buffer to the function, but are not using it.. Have it like this. :-

```
def x(old_buffer):
    list = []
    buffer = old_buffer
    for l in list:
        buffer.append(l)
        if len(buffer) == y:
            return = x(buffer)
        buffer.pop(0)
```

We define function using `def` not `function`...

BTW, what is your purpose of using this -> `return = x(buffer)` way of return. ?? What is that `=` doing in between??

Also, I don't see anything added to the `list` before using it.. Are you pasing any `list` into that `function`?? Else you are re-creating that too on every call..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem:

```
def ema(length):    
    # ...
    for vector in length:
        sum_vector += vector    
        current_vector = vector
    sma = sum_vector / relevant
    if ema_length [relevant] == 0:
        ema_length [relevant] = sma 
    else:
        ema_length [relevant] = (current_vector - ema_length [relevant]) * multiplier + ema_length [relevant]
    return ema_length [relevant]
```

The function `ema` gets a list of values from your buffer. The last element is always the same (as you always call it with `buffer[89 - X:89]`). Now, you loop through the elements, sum them up and set `current_vector` to the current one. After the loop finished, `current_vector` is set to the last one, `buffer[89]`—always. Afterwards you use `current_vector` to set up the return value. So the problem is that you exit the loop to early.

Comment: No. that's not the problem.. `current_vector` is never returned is his code.. This code is working fine if I run on my computer..